# get url that comes encrypted

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem which I have to obtain the parameters of a url but it is encrypted, so when using the queryparams I cut the encrypted url: For example this url **http://localhost:4200/househouse? MGRjYjQ3YWJmMzljYTdlNg==/sfUXx6R6BlTZKIuAPhnfq6dkxg9vsM20P8WuMvf5OkgwedB75cnEC5RM5MCryFk37U4zxdFp7Yiqr/S+QYkD2tsaSChWTgbs3TYVItbc44C6ssJTewkPMyJjhnqIbstdkgIz2v5O4/a524k+lBK2BM/jOEQXoLv/RForpXBmmUz6fvXY5N6kgfIEbjBMngsijmuM4AvGbOfmwJo9US4tA8r1/Zn**

the queryparams takes me as an object as follows:

```
{
NhyddHg: "="
}
```

Then I would like to know how I can get the whole url encrypted (what comes after the first question mark) and not get cut off at "==". Is there a way to do it?

the method is:

```
construcotr(...){
...
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.identificator = params
      console.log("data", params);
    });
}
```

I want to get the following from the url since then I have to decrypt it.

**MGRjYjQ3YWJmMzljYTdlNg==/sfUXx6R6BlTZKIuAPhnfq6dkxg9vsM20P8WuMvf5OkgwedB75cnEC5RM5MCryFk37U4zxdFp7Yiqr/S+QYkD2tsaSChWTgbs3TYVItbc44C6ssJTewkPMyJjhnqIbstdkgIz2v5O4/a524k+lBK2BM/jOEQXoLv/RForpXBmmUz6fvXY5N6kgfIEbjBMngsijmuM4AvGbOfmwJo9US4tA8r1/Zn**

Comment: Why is it not encoded? It should look like `http://localhost:4200/househouse?NhyddHg=%3D%3F%2Ffhgfhfgh6hdhfghf5`

Comment: It is a url that they are sending me which I must decrypt, is that the problem then, how could I encode the url from angular so that it does not have a problem with reserved characters?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `window.location.search` (not the part from angular) you would get:

`?NhyddHg==?/fhgfhfgh6hdhfghf5`

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Exactly, I want to obtain the entire url  (NhyddHg==?/fhgfhfgh6hdhfghf5) so that I can later decrypt it and obtain the parameters it has.

Comment: So is my code what you're looking for? Just do a `console.log(window.location.search)`

Comment: throws me the abbreviated url with a 3d at the end NhyddHg=%3D

Comment: Try decoding that then. `console.log(decodeURIComponent(window.location.search))`

Comment: with that I get up to "NhyddHg ==", it doesn't get what comes after that

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a `#` in there somewhere instead of a `?`. I tried my suggestion on my local computer and it spat out exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: that url was an example, now in the post paste the real url.

Comment: Still works for me. Can you set up a stackblitz?